# Do Gods help us in controlling desires?

Tags: gods, devi, desire

**Do Gods help us controlling desires? Like, would Goddess Laxmi help me destroy my desire for wealth?**

Comment: personal questions are not allowed on forum. please edit your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lust control is incredibly hard. Take Vishwamitra and countless other Rishis who couldn’t control it! It is part of nature. Shani and any Shiva  side deity like Nandi etc. helps you but ultimately YOU have to control it. I mean your soul. It is Nature/ Moola prakriti’s way of protecting the Shiva ‘Role’. Figure out what happens when the fluid raises Upwards. Lot of Ayyappa Bhakthas control it for 2 months before they reach Sabari Mala. Of course there are entities that want you to be Lustful, Desireful etc. Many devas Like Indra ( lord of your sense organs Or Indriyas) do not want you to raise up Kundalini, Does not want your reproductive  fluid to raise up. He sent Apsaras to disrupt VishwaMithras penance.  You raise your soul up that way and he was very close to Brahman and does not want his position to be in jeopardy when your soul raises up.

Look up
‘Ruthigum Sathyam tat Purusham Krishna Pingalam, 
Uurdhuveretham Virupaksham vishwaroopaya vai namaha’

In Sandhyavandanam.

There is no harm in desiring for wealth and working hard to achieve it. 
How many lions in the jungle do you see being fed at their home? They have to work and run and hunt to earn food as well. The King of the Jungle has to work as well for his food. Nature is oriented towards Capitalism! No gods Lakshmi or anyone else will help if YOU don’t do your due diligence for *any* desire. A lion stops hunting after its tummy is Full. Do you have such hard limit for your desire for lust or Money? The critical ‘Lakshmanrekha’ between contentment and greed! As you push the line towards greed, so does your repercussions accumulate which you realize as ‘troubles’ in your life to say the least....
My two cents

Comment: "reproductive fluid to raise up" you mean semen?

Comment: Yes. That’s right. It’s hardened Semen. Technically, it is ‘oordhveredham’. People beat around the bush to mention that. But, tantric books and siddha literature from South India are very clear about that. Upanishads and Veda books eschew them carefully with more euphemistic words...

Answer (score 3):

Except deities of [Panchayatana Puja](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panchayatana_puja) i.e. **Vishnu, Shiva, Durga, Ganesha, Surya and their manifestations**, none will help you in controlling your desires or liberating you. These are also known as Shiva's [five faces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadyojata) called Ishana(Shiva), Tatpurusha(Ganesha), Aghora(Surya), Vamadeva(Vishnu) and Sadyojatha(Devi) or  creation, preservation, dissolution, concealing grace and revealing grace. God created man in his image, hence as per Vedas, [Shivoham](https://omshivoham.com/blogs/blog/shivoham-meaning) - "I am Shiva"

> [Brahman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahman) was this before; therefore it knew even the Ātma (soul,
>   himself). I am Brahman, therefore it became all. And whoever among the gods had this
>   enlightenment, also became That. It is the same with the sages, the
>   same with men. **Whoever knows the self as “I am Brahman,” becomes all
>   this universe.** Even the gods cannot prevail against him, for he
>   becomes their Ātma. Now, if a man worships another god, thinking: “He
>   is one and I am another,” he does not know. He is like an animal to
>   the gods. **As many animals serve a man, so does each man serve the
>   gods. Even if one animal is taken away, it causes anguish; how much
>   more so when many are taken away? Therefore it is not pleasing to the
>   gods that men should know this.** — Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 1.4.1

[Geeta](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/7)

> Bhagavad Gita 7.20 Those whose knowledge has been carried away by
>   material desires surrender to the celestial gods. Following their own
>   nature, they worship the devatās, practicing rituals meant to
>   propitiate these celestial personalities.
>
> Bhagavad Gita 7.21 Whatever celestial form a devotee seeks to worship
>   with faith, I steady the faith of such a devotee in that form.
>
> Bhagavad Gita 7.22 Endowed with faith, the devotee worships a
>   particular celestial god and obtains the objects of desire. But in
>   reality I alone arrange these benefits.
>
> Bhagavad Gita 7.23 But the fruit gained by these people of small
>   understanding is perishable. Those who worship the celestial gods go
>   to the celestial abodes, while my devotees come to me.
>
> Bhagavad Gita 7.24 The less intelligent think that I, the Supreme Lord
>   Shree Krishna, was formless earlier and have now assumed this
>   personality. They do not understand the imperishable exalted nature of
>   my personal form.
>
> Bhagavad Gita 7.25 I am not manifest to everyone, being veiled by my
>   divine Yogmaya energy. Hence, those without knowledge do not know that
>   I am without birth and changeless.

All the gods like Shani, Laxmi etc., are extensions of Purush-Prakriti couple **i.e. Shiva-Kaali(for introvert people) or Radha-Krishna(for extrovert people).**